# awk printed out only one matching line when multiple terms in the first column in file1 matched to the first column in file2

Tags: awk, grep, matching, carriage-return

I know similar questions have been asked multiple times, but I was not able to get the code to work with my files. 
I have one column in my file 1 and multiple columns in my file 2. What I wanted to do is exactly like what the person asked in this post, which is if column 1 in file 1 matches column 1 in file 2, print out the entire line in file 2. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334448/if-column-matches-another-file-print-every-line-with-match-awk-grep?noredirect=1&lq=1

I tried `awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]>0' file1 file2` and also tried re-formatting my files following the code, but no success.

```
tr '\r' '\n' < file1 > file1.new
mv file1.new file1
tr '\r' '\n' < file2 > file2.new
mv file2.new file2
```

The problem I am having is that awk only prints out one of the matching lines (not the first matching line). I am sure there are multiple matching lines because I checked it with grep.

I was wondering if anyone knows the potential cause of it. Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

***1st solution:*** Use removal of control M logic in `awk` itself.

```
awk '{gsub(/\r/,"")} NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]>0' file1
```

***2nd solution:*** Remove them by `tr` and then use `awk`(trying to fix OP's attempt itself).

```
tr -d '\r' < file1 > file1.new
tr -d '\r' < file2 > file2.new
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, I tried both, they all worked! Thanks for your great help!! But could you explain what control M logic means in awk? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jing, `\r` denotes control M characters(windows ending chars) by using `gsub` I am simply removing them (in other words substituting them with NULL), lemme know in case of any more queries please, cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Really appreciated your help!